# Is it possible to obtain result set of a sp as a table that I can query?

Tags: stored-procedures, set

Is it possitble to get a stored-procedure's result set as a table so that I can query that? 
something like:

SELECT PK_Item, Count(PK_Item)
FROM (pMyStoredProcedure) --This sp returns a table that has PK_Item column
GROUP BY PK_ITEM
ORDER BY PK_ITEM DESC

I am not an T-SQL expert but my friend says it is kind of impossible to do this with sprocs.

Is not there any way? But without modifying the stored procedure.

thanks!

Comment: From your sample code, I assume that SP has no parameter, yea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the table structure that the sp will return using sql server 2005

you can use

```
declare @table table(
  columns here...
)

INSERT INTO  @table exec your_sp params

select * from @table
```

Comment: What if the sp returns 2 or more tables as a result set?